# Como faço estilização de codes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Como faço para estilizar um code ?
Por exemplo:
Postei esse código no meu blog:

```
<?= "Olá :D"; ?>
```

Só que ele vai exibir normal, como um texto, mas dentro da tag `<pre></pre>`.

Porém a minha dúvida é, como faço para estilizar e deixar visível para meus leitores assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E dependendo da linguagem, a estilização fica diferente.
No meu formulário consigo selecionar o tipo de code.. `<pre><code class="language-php"><?= "Olá :D"; ?></code></pre>`

Comment: Leia sobre o [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/).

Comment: você pode tentar também gituhb gist.

Comment: Obrigado Anderson era isso mesmo :)